# VHDL - Store two inputs from Terminal

Tags: input, vhdl, putty

I would like to sum together two input values. I am using a PuTTY terminal to provide the input to my top level module. This looks as follows

```
entity top_level is
    port(...dataIn_pin : in STD_LOGIC...); --not including other ports here e.g. clk, reset
end top_level;
```

The architecture body is then defined as

```
architecture structural of top_level is
    signal inputA : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal inputB : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    ...
end structural;
```

How might I store two inputs from the terminal in `inputA` and `inputB` respectively? For example I would type '24' in the terminal and `inputA` would contain '2' and `inputB` would contain '4'.

Comment: There's something called a Universal Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter (UART) and you want the receiver part, although I can imagine you wanting a transmitter sooner or later.

Comment: Using the receiver (which I have code for) would I wait for a number of bits to be received equal to the total number of bits in two characters input from the terminal?

Comment: Your receiver will generally tell you when a received word is assembled and needs to be transferred.  Without a FIFO you need to parallel load it somewhere else in 2 - 2.5 clocks (1 - 1.5 stop bits depending on number of data bits and baud rate, plus one start bit time).  Adding an output register gives you an entire word time.

Comment: Ok thanks for that information. My receiver transfers a `std_logic_vector` of 8 bits to the UART and to `top_level` for an input. I am able to display this input in the terminal via a transmitter. However, what method would you use to transfer one input to `top_level` and store in `inputA`, and then store the next input in `inputB`?

Comment: I get the impression after seeing you ask two VHDL questions you might get a bit more organized before asking.  Now all the sudden you're relating using a UART transmitter.